# Error when changing DB engine from MyIsam to innoDB

Tags: java, mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I've changed my DB engine of my Java webapplication to innoDB from MyIsam. I'm using a MySql DB. For some reason I now get an error on the creation of my db tables which are added through a batch.

The error i get is: `java.sql.BatchUpdateException`.

What are the implications of changing between these two DB engines and how do I correct what I've wronged?

**EDIT**

The complete stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table 'schedule.course2user' (errno: 150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2690)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1567)
    at database.DBCreator.execList(DBCreator.java:203)
    at database.DBCreator.createDatabase(DBCreator.java:215)
    at database.DBCreator.main(DBCreator.java:248)
```

The DB commands that are not working with innoDB but worked with MyIsam:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedule`.`course` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`description` BLOB ,
`credits` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' ,
`capacity` INT DEFAULT '0' ,
`isRemoved` TINYINT(1)  NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`groupId` INT  NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`creatorId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
INDEX `fk_creator` (`creatorId` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorId` )REFERENCES `schedule`.`course` (`id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ) 
ENGINE = innoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: You need to provide us with the complete stack trace.

Comment: Without seeing your table definitions, we won't be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: @OrangeDog I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it finally, And with little time to go with this project.

The problem is that InnoDB unlike MyIsam cannot use an unsigned int as a foreign key.

In my example I had to change the

```
`creatorId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

line: to

```
`creatorId` INT NOT NULL,
```

pretty simple I just didn't know it acted this way.

Answer (score 0):

A database with the `InnoDB`-engine requires an index-field per table (which can be a `index` or a `Primary Key` or even a `Foreign Key`).

So, your problem seams to be that there is no defined index (or key) which the engine can use. You should declare a `Primary Key` for every table you're creating.

The `MyISAM`-engine doesn't require this.

Comment: You can have multiple column pk in innodb as well as myisam

Comment: So this answer doesn't help since I already have a Primary key (sometimes several) for these tables